# react-native-navigation-redux-helpers navigation to login page

Tags: react-native, redux, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a react-native redux application, first login page comes and then it enters into the application and navigates from "HomePage" to other page and again back to homepage.
Now, I want to logout the application and has written code to navigate to logout but it is giving error in index of renderscene.

I have to send it to login page which is working fine but again when i am trying to login into the application its throwing error.

```
import { cardStackReducer } from 'react-native-navigation-redux-helpers';

const initialState = {
  key: 'global',
  index: 0,
  routes: [
    {
      key: 'login',
      index: 0,
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = cardStackReducer(initialState);
```

Comment: getting the error navigationState.routes[1].key "scene_home" conflicts with another route!. Actually I want to know how and where i can reset the stack because I can see while debugging that it is trying to push homepage again on stack i.e. on logout stack is not reset.

Comment: `cardStackReducer ` has `reset` method, take a look here at the bottom: https://github.com/bakery/react-native-navigation-redux-helpers for available actions

Comment: Thanks, done that. this.props.reset(this.props.navigation.key);

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that

> this.props.reset(this.props.navigation.key);

doesn't work for me.

But I found that using reset with the correct parameters of react-native-navigation-redux-helpers action works.

```
this.props.reset([
    {
        key: 'login',
        index: 0,
    },
], key, 0);
```